# Encountering Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined in React.js using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, react

I am encountering Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined. I am rendering it in OpenLayers using a MERN application.  I have checked that the API call for the GeoJSON is returning correctly the data, though I am not sure if it is the right format. Could you check my code if this is the correct way to read and render the data? I have checked similar issues and they suggest to change the projection.  Is my projection right? Or is it the way I store the data in the database that is the issue?

DataLayer.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";


const DataLayer = ({ map, layerType }) => {
    const [layers, setLayers] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        if (layerType === 'fireIncident') {
          const res = await fetch(`/api/fire_incident`);
          const data = await res.json();
  
            if (data && data.length > 0 ) {
            const wktOptions = {
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            }
            const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
                features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, wktOptions),
            });
  
            console.log('GeoJSON data:', data)
            const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
                source: vectorSource,
            });
  
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            setLayers((layers) => [...layers, vectorLayer]);
            }
        }
      };
  
      fetchData();
    }, [map, layerType]);
  
    return null;
  };
  
  export default DataLayer;
```

Basemap.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import 'ol/ol.css';

const BaseMap = ({ center, zoom, children }) => {
  const mapElement = useRef();
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat(center),
        zoom: zoom,
      }),
    });

    setMap(initialMap);
    return () => initialMap.setTarget(null);
  }, [center, zoom]);

  return (
    <div id="map" ref={mapElement} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}>
      {children(map)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BaseMap;
```

Here is the GeoJSON data from the API call which returns 2 results:

```
[{"properties":{"incyr":2019,"month":"February","penro":"PPG","cenro":"","location":"Brgy Diaz","occur_date":"2019-02-10T00:00:00.000Z","cause":2,"area_damage":1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[120.51350683576823,15.099785805351729]},"_id":"6547bc4174377cd1cbd44415","type":"Feature","__v":0},{"properties":{"incyr":2020,"month":"March","penro":"PPG","cenro":"","location":"San Vicente","occur_date":"2020-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","cause":1,"area_damage":0.5},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[120.73099597560082,15.233933632945224]},"_id":"6547bc6174377cd1cbd44417","type":"Feature","__v":0}]
```

Mongoose schema:

```
const fireIncidentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Feature'],
    required: true
  },
  properties: {
    incyr: Number,
    month: String,
    penro: String,
    cenro: String,
    location: String,
    occur_date: Date,
    cause: Number,
    area_damage: Number
  },
  geometry: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readFeatures` expects a GeoJSON feature collection, your data is a array of feature jsons which must be read individually:

```
  const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features: data.map((f) => new GeoJSON().readFeature(f, wktOptions))
  });
```

Comment: The error I am encountering now is Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: feature.getId is not a function.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to remove the 's' from readFeatures.  Thank you. It is now working.